# Adjoint matrix in $\mathbb{so_3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\mathbb{so_3}$ has the following basis: $X_1=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & & \\ & &1 \\  & -1 &  \end{bmatrix}$, s: $X_2=\begin{bmatrix}  & & 1\\ & 0& \\ -1 &  &  \end{bmatrix}$ and $X_3=\begin{bmatrix}  & 1& \\ =1& & \\  & & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

**Write down the matrix $ad_{X_1}$ with respect to the above basis $\{X_1, X_2, X_3 \}$**

I know that $[X_1, X_2]=X_3$, $[X_2, X_3]=X_1$ and $[X_3, X_1]=X_2$

Also, $\mathbb{so_3}=\{ X \in \mathbb{sl_3(R)} : X + {^t}X=0 \}$ which is of dimension $3$

How can we use these facts  (or others?) to compute, say, $ad_{X_1}$?

I think it will be a $3 \times 3$ matrix

Answer (score 1):

Identifying $X_1,X_2,X_3$ with the standard basis $\Bigg\{
\left(
\begin{array}{l} 
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end{array}
\right)$,
$\left(\begin{array}{l}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{array}\right)$,
$\left(\begin{array}{c} 
0  \\ 0  \\ 1 
\end{array}\right)
\Bigg\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we get:
$$X_1\mapsto ad_{X_1}=\Big[ad_{X_1}(X_1),ad_{X_1}(X_2),ad_{X_1}(X_3)\Big]=\Big[[X_1,X_1],[X_1,X_2],[X_1,X_3]\Big]=  \\ =\Big[0,X_3,-X_2\Big]=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & -1  \\
0  & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) \in End(so(3))
$$